# Javascript object doesn't accept JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following script:

```
const [firstResponse, secondResponse] = await Promise.all([
   this.$store.dispatch(Actions.RELATIONS),
   ApiService.get("/api/"+ this.apiEndpointSingle +'/'+this.uid)
]);

console.log(secondResponse)
this.formData = secondResponse.data.result[this.apiEndpointSingle];
```

If I console log the secondResponse (it make a valid JSON value at the key empty). How can I fix this? It's very wierd in my opinion. I never saw this earlier.

Output API:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "created_at": "2021-06-15T12:10:41.000000Z",
  "updated_at": null,
  "created_by": 1,
  "status": 1,
  "uid": null,
  "tags": "[\"2\"]",
  "sale_status": "completed",
  "reference": "test1",
  "sale_date": "2021-06-17T14:33:00.000000Z",
  "currency": null,
  "connection_id": null,
  "relation_id": 1,
  "profile_id": 1,
  "address_id": 1,
  "profile_name": "P1",
  "relation_name": "R1"
}
```

Output after console logged the variable `secondResponse`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-06-15T12:10:41.000000Z",
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_by": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "uid": null,
    "tags": [],
    "sale_status": "completed",
    "reference": "test1",
    "sale_date": "2021-06-17T14:33:00.000000Z",
    "currency": null,
    "connection_id": null,
    "relation_id": 1,
    "profile_id": 1,
    "address_id": 1,
    "profile_name": "P1",
    "relation_name": "R1"
}
```

Comment: *If I console log the secondResponse (it make a valid JSON value at the key empty)* is not a complete sentence.. at the key *empty*? Please describe what you have and what you want. I am guessing you mean the `"tags"` value? The backend is settings that array incorrectly as a string: `"tags": "[\"2\"]",`. This should be `"tags": [2],` instead.

Comment: There's no `data` property in `secondResponse`. What is `secondResponse.data.result` supposed to be?

Comment: What I mean is `tags`. If I check the network, it shows a variable. If I console log the output of the axios call, I get a empty `tags`.

Comment: Pls. attach `console.log( secondResponse.data)` and `console.log(this.apiEndpointSingle)`.
the `tag: "[\"2\"]"` value is a string not an array!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It hasn't anything todo with this part of the script. It is v-model system which replaces data afterwards.